# the significance of the period in "./bin/python"

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

I'm trying to do the steps in the "Quick Installation" portion of https://github.com/plumi/plumi.app/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.rst

I did Step 1 by replacing the # with sudo

In Step 2, I included the period after virtualenv in "~/plumi.app$virtualenv ." and something happened (nothing happened when I didn't include the period), so I'm assuming it worked.

I skipped Step 3 because I'm just running a test/development instance.

When I try Step 4, I get errors. I'm assuming I'm missing the significance of the period in "./bin/python bootstrap.py" and "./bin/buildout"

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `./` is unnecessary, `bin/python` would have the same effect, running `python` under the `bin` subdirectory of the current directory. Of course, neither should be confused with `/bin/python`, which means something entirely different, as Blender explained, and would run the system `python`.

In my experience, `./bin/python` in preference to `bin/python` is a result of habit. Many people run shells set up not to include `.` in `PATH`, because of which they must invoke executables in the current directory as `./exec-name`, compared with just `exec-name`. (This is a good practice, because then you don't need to worry about accidentally running a malicious script just by cd-ing into a directory and typing the wrong command.) However, having `.` in `PATH` has no effect on a command such as `bin/python`, because such relative commands are never looked up in `PATH` in the first place. In other words, `bin/python` is identical to `./bin/python` regardless of `PATH`.

Comment: @user4815162342 will Linux interpret it correctly if I use ./bin/python? Or do I have to use bin/python?

Comment: @user1883050 As stated in the first sentence of the answer, the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

/bin/python points to the absolute path of your system,that resolves at

**/** < root directory

**bin** < bin directory under /

**python** < python directory under /bin/

while ./bin/python points to

**.**  < the working directory you are currently on

**bin** < the bin directory under your current working directory

**python** < the python directory under ./bin

if you instead type bin/python , you should be able to get the same result, adding ./ at the front is a "safe way" to execute a command.